# Number theory - enumerating pairs satisfying a property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

*Problem: Find all ordered pairs of positive integers $a,b$ such that $(a,b) = s$ and $[a,b] = ks$, where is a given strictly positive integer.*

The notation I will use in this post is that the g.c.d of $a$ and $b$ will be denoted $(a,b)$ and the l.c.m will be denoted $[a,b]$.

I've come up with the following solution that I feel is quite sketchy - the part that makes me uneasy has been **bolded.**

To begin, we state our problem as that of looking for solutions to this set of simultaneous equations:
$$\begin{align}(a,b)&=s\\ [a,b]&=ks\end{align}.$$
First, we recall the formula $[a,b]=\frac{\vert ab\vert}{(a,b)}$ from basic number theory, and use this to find
$$ks = [a,b] = \frac{ab}{(a,b)} = \frac{ab}s \implies \large{ab=ks^2}.$$
Rearranging this equation (which is valid since $a$ and $b$ are already integers), gives us then that
$$b = \frac{ks^2}a.$$
Substituting into our first original equation, we find that our original problem **has been reformulated as**
$$(a,\frac{ks^2}a)=s.$$
Since $s\vert a$, this implies that $a\geq s$. Since $s\vert\frac{ks^2}a$, it follows that $s\leq\frac{ks^2}a$ and therefore, rearranging we find $s\leq a\leq ks$. Hence we have drastically reduced the area in which to search for solutions. Two obvious such solutions are $a = s$ and $a = ks$; these can be checked by simple substitution. It is easy to check that there are no other solutions. Therefore, the only possible solutions are
$$\begin{align}
a=s,\,\,\,\,b=ks\\
a=ks,\,\,\,\,b=s.
\end{align}$$

Comments: The bolded phrase phrase implies some sort of equivalence between the original system and the new equation. I'm not entirely sure I'm allowed to assume the other direction of implication - am I? If not, then this entire proof is basically a Rube Goldberg machine to find pairs that were already quite obvious before I had started.

Comment: this is not right. consider $s = 16, k= 15.$ then you can easily check that $a= 48, b= 80.$

Comment: Did I go wrong in the spot that I bolded?

Comment: that bolded part is fine. you are just replacing $b$ by $\frac{ks^2}{a}.$ the problem comes after that. the "obvious choice" is not right.

Comment: @Krish: The obvious choices are in fact both obvious and correct; the problem comes a little further on, with the claim that they’re the only solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a, b) = s \Rightarrow a = a_1s, b=b_1s,$ for some $a_1, b_1 \in \mathbb{N}.$ So $ks = [a, b] = \frac{ab}{(a, b)} = \frac{s^2a_1b_1}{s(a_1, b_1)} = \frac{sa_1b_1}{(a_1, b_1)} \Rightarrow [a_1, b_1] = k.$ So we have $(a_1, b_1) = 1, [a_1, b_1] = k.$

Consider the following example: $(a, b)=16, [a,b] = 240.$ Now $a = 16a_1, b = 16b_1,$ for some $a_1, b_1 \in \mathbb{N}.$ So $(a_1, b_1) = 1, [a_1, b_1] = 15$ (this is actually the reduction step). From this the only choices are $a_1 =3, b_1 = 5$ or $a_1 = 5, b_1 = 3.$ On the other hand, if we start with $(a, b) = 16, [a, b]= 1120,$ then we will have $[a_1, b_1] = 70 = 2 \times 5 \times 7.$ So in this case there are more possibilities for $a_1$ and $b_1$: $(2,35), (10, 7), (14, 5), (5, 14), (35, 2), (7, 10)...$

I think the number of possibilities for $a_1, b_1$ can be counted by factoring $k$ into prime factors and then taking all possible combinations satisfying $(a_1, b_1) =1, [a_1, b_1]=k.$